# Count the number of matching post names in foreach loop

Tags: php, posts, loop, count

I have a simple foreach loop that outputs an ordered list from a CPT 'post_subscribers' and an associated meta key called 'project'.

```
$theposts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'post_subscriber',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => -1,
) ); 


echo '<ol>';
    foreach( $theposts as $p ): 

        $project_name = get_post_meta($p->ID, 'project', true);

        echo '<li class="mb-3">';

            echo get_the_title($project_name);
        
        echo '</li>';
    
    endforeach;

echo '</ol>'; 

echo 'Total projects - '. count($theposts)."</br>";
```

My list will generate:

1. Project title one
2. Project title two
3. Project title two
4. Project title two
5. Project title three
6. Project title one

Total projects - 6

Q) Within my generated ordered list there are several exact matching '$project_name'(s). How can I count the multiple matching '$project_name' entries and display the count for each of them as separate results? (As I have 300+ in my generated list).

EG result: There are 3 projects with the name 'Project title two'.

It seems like a relatively simple task but I can't get my head around it? Many thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get the count of a variable number of repeated titles by using an indexed array.

```php
$theposts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'   => 'post_subscriber',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => -1,
) ); 

// project titles counter, outside the loop
$project_titles = array();

foreach( $theposts as $p ): 

    $project_name = get_post_meta($p->ID, 'project', true);
    echo '<ol>';
        echo '<li class="mb-3">';
            $project_title = get_the_title($project_name);
            echo $project_title;

            // check if $project_titles contains $project_title already
            if ( array_key_exists( $project_title, $project_titles) ) :
                $project_titles[$project_title]++;
            else : // otherwise, initialize key value pair with 1
                $project_titles[$project_title] = 1;
            endif;
        
        echo '</li>';
    echo '</ol>';    
endforeach;

// loop through and print all
foreach ($project_titles as $project_title => $project_title_count) :
    if ($project_title_count > 1) : // repeated
        echo 'There are ' . $project_title_count . ' projects with the name ' . $project_title . '.<br/>';
    endif;
endforeach;
```

`$project_titles` will now store the number of times each title is repeated as a key-value pair. The key will be your project's title, and the value will be the number of times that project's title exists.

**EDIT:** Removed first code block since it wasn't useful with question update. Updated second block of code to accommodate a variable number of repeated titles.

Comment: Hi @YourManDan, that was very helpful :-) and worked well for a '$project_title' conditional check against a single static string (IE: 'Project title two'). I have over 300+ projects with multiple exact matching entries (In my list). In the second (2) solution you have provided - what would be the approach / conditional check for counting multiple matching entries dynamically? (I ask politely). Any help appreciated :-)

Comment: @dekkyd If I understand correctly, you're wanting a way to output (as per your example): "There are 3 projects with the name 'Project title two'. There are 2 projects with the name 'Project title one'." etc. You want a way to get the count of _all_ projects with the same title?

Comment: Correct! and thanks for getting back to me :-)

Comment: I have also been looking at this other post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296752/count-identical-post-titles for some guidance?

Comment: @dekkyd Ah excellent timing, was literally typing out basically that post as you commented :) slightly different, but I've updated my answer now. Please update your question to clarify the 'multiple matching entries dynamically' clarification you had for me for any future passing-byers.

Comment: you the man! Thanks so much for your time and effort. Exactly what I was looking for :-) Have updated the original question as you have suggested.